# InitialializeComponent() with data template wpf

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

How does the InitializeComponent()(used to create controls in wpf) work when there is a data template used.  Is the view created each time the binding object changes?

Comment: What's the purpose of your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that the view would be regenerated each time the binding changes. It just updates collections and views (controls) concerned with the update. otherwise it would consume a lot of resources.